# How to combine postcss / autoprefixer with LESS

Tags: less, gulp, autoprefixer

I have a site for which I use custom LESS stylesheets and they include Bootstrap LESS stylesheets. It is all compiled to the final `style.css` file with a `style.css.map` sourcemap.

This is how my Gulpfile looks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less-sourcemap');

var mySite = '.';

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src(mySite + '/css/**.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(mySite + '/css'));
});
```

Now I'd like to add [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). This is what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less-sourcemap');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');

var mySite = '.';

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src(mySite + '/css/**.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })]))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(mySite + '/css'));
});
```

It's because I am piping the generated sourcemaps into `postcss` and it cannot handle it. So I've tried this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less-sourcemap');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');

var mySite = '.';

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src(mySite + '/css/**.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })]))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(mySite + '/css'));


    gulp.src(mySite + '/css/**.css')
      .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })]))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(mySite + '/css'));
});
```

However, the prefixes are still not added. Maybe it's because the Bootstrap's CSS is already prefixed and it's somehow a problem for `postcss`?

How to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less), [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps), and [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) instead? That seems to work fine for me.

Comment: It's just incorrect to to have two gulp streams in a single task. After splitting my single `less` task to `less` and `autoprefix` and making `autoprefix` depend on `less`, all works fine.

Comment: So you decided to let your `less` task write the css files to disk, and then your `autoprefix` task reads the css files from disk?

Comment: Yes. It seems that `autoprefixer` updates the sourcemaps as well so all seems to be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Gulp-Less Readme](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less),

> If you are using version 1.3.7 or higher you will have the ability to
>   use a growing set LESS plugins, potentially simplifying your build
>   steps.

And the code they suggest using would look like this.

```
var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefix= new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});


gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
  .pipe(less({
    plugins: [autoprefix]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
```

Comment: thankyou - this resolved my issue after a good hour or two searching for correct solution re less x autoprefixing